# Possibility to search ID Properties in search property

Tags: python, properties

Is it possible to search ID Properties in a search_prop String Property and if, how ?

The code below seems not to work obviously because the items() and keys() function don't gives data.

```
box.prop_search(bpy.context.scene, "deleteNameProp", bpy.context.active_object, "items()")
box.prop_search(bpy.context.scene, "deleteNameProp", bpy.context.active_object, "keys()")
```

Comment: I'd use a callback. Here is a test: https://gist.github.com/p2or/e14a6470be25e87ed596 to get custom *material properties*, although I am not sure whether there is a *cleaner* way of doing this.